# Google Sheets Auto-Populate the author for each row on change of column B

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I add an auto-populate of the user who last edited the row to the following code that auto-populates the date the column was last edited.  Here is the current script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
        cols = [2],
        colStamp = 1,
        ind = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
        if (s.getName() !== 'Log' || ind == -1) return;
    e.range.offset(0, parseInt(colStamp - cols[ind]))
        .setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);
}
```

So, ultimately... I would want to add the user name to column G on edit of each row.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve user name using Class Session. The detail information is here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session

Please add following script to last row of your script. The user name is imported to column G. If you want user e-mail, please change from `getUsername()` to `getEmail()`.

**Script :**

```
s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 7).setValue(Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername());
```

**About `onEdit()`**

If the `onEdit()` is not installed as a trigger, other shared users cannot use `Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername()` because of `authMode=LIMITED`. So the user name cannot be retrieved. By installing `onEdit()` as a trigger, `authMode` becomes `FULL`. So you can retrieve user data using `Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername()`.

The detail information for installing trigger is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

**Added 1 :**

In order to retrieve user information, the user has to install a trigger for `onEdit()`. I had forgotten about this. I'm sorry.

For example, owner of spreadsheet and user with a permission for editing are OWNER and USER, respectively. When OWNER installs a trigger for `onEdit()`, the user of spreadsheet becomes OWNER. At this time, when USER edits the spreadsheet, the user name becomes OWNER.

When I have worked a test, I have installed as USER. So I had thought that it works. But it was wrong. So I thought for the solution as follows.

1. Install a trigger for `onEdit()` using `onOpen()`.

   - This didn't work, as you know.
2. Display a dialog box and a button using `onOpen()`. Install a trigger for `onEdit()` by the button.

   - This didn't work, because of existing several triggers for each user.
3. Display a dialog box and a button using `onOpen()`. while temporarily install a trigger for `onEdit()`, retrieve the user name and put it to cache by the button. The trigger is removed after retrieved user name soon.

   - This works fine.

I propose the 3rd method. In this script, it is not necessary to install triggers manually. If you want to change the hold time of cache, please modify `cache.put()`.

**Script :**

```
function getUser() {
  var triggerId = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onEdit()
    .create().getUniqueId();
  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (i in triggers) {
    if (triggers[i].getUniqueId() == triggerId) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  cache.put("username", user, 3600); // For example, hold user name for 1 h
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(
    HtmlService 
    .createHtmlOutput('<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close()}).getUser()">')
    .setTitle('Push OK button.')
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(100)
  );
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var user = cache.get("username"); // Please use this as user name.
}
```

**Flow of script :**

1. When spreadsheet is opened, a dialog is opened on the spreadsheet by `onOpen()`.
2. When user pushes "ok", the user name is retrieved and put to the cache by `getUser()`.
3. When user edits the spreadsheet, the user name is retrieved from the cache by `onEdit()`.

Please copy and paste this script. You can use `user` in `onEdit()`.

When I have been confirming this again, I noticed that in order to use this script, each user has to be authorized. The authorization is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

**Added 2 :**

I report a solution for retrieving shared user information at spreadsheet. It was found as follows.

- User information retrieving by Class Session is the owner and users which installed triggers by themselves.
- When each user installs a trigger, user information retrieving by Class Session losts the accuracy. So user information has to be retrieved using a temporally installed trigger.
- Using `onOpen()`, it cannot directly install triggers and authorize.
- Using menu bar, it can install triggers and authorize Google Services using API.

Here, I thought 2 problems.

1. The confirmation whether the authorization was done.

   - At `onOpen()`, although many methods using Google API can be executed without the authorization, there are also some methods which cannot be executed without the authorization. Furthermore, there are some methods which cannot execute even if the authorization was done. It's `trigger`. On the other hand, `DriveApp` requires the authorization for only the first time, but it can use without the authorization after 2nd times.
2. I thought that users can find easily by displaying information in a dialog box when spreadsheet is launched. So I adopted displaying information using the dialog box. But, there is a big limitation for the dialog box.

   - Using a click of button on a dialog box, it can install triggers. However it cannot authorize Google Services using API.

Using above information, I thought a flow to retrieve user information.

1. When user opens the spreadsheet for the first time, it displays 'Please authorize at "Authorization" of menu bar.' using a dialog box, and creates a menu bar "Authorization".
2. The user clicks "OK" button on the dialog box and run "Authorization" at the menu bar. By running "Authorization", the user information is retrieved by a temporally installed trigger.
3. When the user opens the spreadsheet after the 2nd time, the authorization is checked by `DriveApp`. A dialog box with 'Push OK button.' is displayed. By clicking "OK", the user information is retrieved by a temporally installed trigger.

By this flow, the user information which is using the shared spreadsheet can be retrieved. Although I think that there may be also other solutions, I proposal this as one of solutions.

**Script :**

```
function getUser(){
  var triggerId = ScriptApp.newTrigger('getUser')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onEdit()
    .create()
    .getUniqueId();
  var userInf = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var userName = userInf.getUsername();
  var userMail = userInf.getEmail();
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  [ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(i) for each (i in triggers) if (i.getUniqueId() == triggerId)];
  CacheService.getUserCache().putAll({
    "username": userName,
    "usermail": userMail
  }, 3600);
}

function dialogForGetUser(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(
    HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<input type="button"\
      value="OK"\
      onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close()})\
      .getUser()">'
    )
    .setTitle('Push OK button.')
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(100)
  );
}

function dialogForAuth(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(
    HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<input type="button"\
      value="OK"\
      onclick="google.script.host.close()">'
    )
    .setTitle('Please authorize at "Authorization" of menu bar.')
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(100)
  );
}

function getAuth() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.removeMenu("Authorization");
  getUser();
  ss.toast("Done.", "Authorization", 3);
}

function onOpen(){
  try {
    var temp = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
    dialogForGetUser();
  } catch(e) {
    dialogForAuth();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
      "Authorization",
      [{
        functionName:"getAuth",
        name:"Run this only when the first time"
      }]
    );
  }
}

function onEdit(e){
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var user = cache.getAll(["username", "usermail"]);

  // user.username is user name.
}
```

1. When the spreadsheet is opened, at first, `onOpen()` is executed. It is checked whether the user has already authorized.
2. If the user has never authorized yet, `dialogForAuth()` is executed. If the user has already authorized. `dialogForGetUser()` is executed.

In this case, you can retrieve user name by `user.username` at `onEdit()`.

Comment: I don't think this will work, since onEdit is run on no [authorization mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()). Unless all the users of the sheet have given permission to the script.

Comment: @Jack Brown Thank you for your comment. I confirmed that user name, which is a shared user, can be retrieved by installing ``onEdit()`` as a trigger. And updated my answer.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  It did require the trigger to be installed but works like a charm.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @tmman I still a little confused, if a user "A" installs the trigger for a function. The function will always run under user "A" authorization and hence session.getEffectiveUser would be User "A". I ask this because i setup the above code with my consumer gmail account and when edited it with by school G suite account, the effective user is the gmail user. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @JackBrown, you are correct... I was just testing this and noticed the same problem.  No matter who is editing the sheet, my user name is populated. Tanaike, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I updated my answer as "Added" just now. Please check it. And thank you for your advice @Jack Brown. I had forgotten user information for a trigger.

Comment: I answered a solution of this problem as an update. Please check it.